# Python Data Scraping (using Xpath) - Returning empty lists and stripping characters

Tags: python-2.7

--

I am attempting to scrape information from the website:

```
http://www.forexfactory.com/#tradesPositions
```

Now, I used to have one up and running which this forum helped me get going, but I think something has changed on the website and the script I had no longer works.

### What do I need?

I would like to scrape the number of 'short' and 'long' positions for AUDUSD, EURUSD, GBPUSD, USDJPY, USDCAD, NZDUSD and USDCHF.

NOT the percentages, the actual number of traders.

[image]

### What have I done?

***This is for EURUSD***

```
import lxml.html
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\MY NAME\Downloads\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe")
url = ('http://www.forexfactory.com/#tradesPositions')
driver.get(url)


tree = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
results_short = tree.xpath('//*[@id="flexBox_flex_trades/positions_tradesPositionsCopy1"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/span/text()')
results_long = tree.xpath('//*[@id="flexBox_flex_trades/positions_tradesPositionsCopy1"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/span/text()')


print "Forex Factory"
print "Traders Short EURUSD:",results_short
print "Traders Long EURUSD:",results_long
driver.quit()
```

This returns

```
Forex Factory
Traders Short EURUSD: ['337 Traders ', ' ']
Traders Long EURUSD: [' 259 Traders']
```

I would like to strip everything away from the result except for the numbers. I've tried .strip() and .replace() but neither work on a list. Which will come as no surprise to you guys I don't think!

### Empty List

When I apply the same technique to AUDUSD I get an empty list.

```
import lxml.html
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\Andrew G\Downloads\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe")
url = ('http://www.forexfactory.com/#tradesPositions')
driver.get(url)


tree = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
results_short = tree.xpath('//*[@id="flexBox_flex_trades/positions_tradesPositionsCopy1"]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/span/text()')
results_long = tree.xpath('//*[@id="flexBox_flex_trades/positions_tradesPositionsCopy1"]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/span/text()')

s2 = results_short
l2 = results_long


print "Traders Short AUDUSD:",s2
print "Traders Long AUDUSD:",l2
```

This returns

```
Traders Short AUDUSD: []
Traders Long AUDUSD: []
```

What gives? Is the Xpath not working? Just use Chromes 'inspect element' feature and navigated to the desired number, and copied the path. Same method for EURUSD.

---

Ideally, It would be nice to set up a list of div numbers that can insert into the tree.xpath instead of repeating the lines of code for all the different currencies to make it neater. So, in the Xpath where it has:

```
/div[number]/
```

It would be nice to have a list, i.e [1,2,3,4,5,6] that can insert into that because the rest of the Xpath is the same for the currencies. Anyway, that's an optional bonus, priority is to get a return for all currencies listed.

---

### THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all the space inside your result as you mentioned with strip method, here is my sample code:

```
for index in range(len(results_short)):
    results_short[index] = results_short[index].strip()

    if results_short[index] == "":
        del results_short[index]

for index in range(len(results_long)):
    results_long[index] = results_long[index].strip()

    if results_long[index] == "":
        del results_long[index]
```

For the problem you cannot get the result of AUD because the values are not loaded to the page until you have clicked the "expand" button. But I have found you can get the result from the following page: http://www.forexfactory.com/trades.php

So you can change the value of url as:

```
url = ('http://www.forexfactory.com/trades.php')
```

For this page, since the name of CSS id has changed, you need to update your value to:

```
results_short = tree.xpath('//*[@id="flexBox_flex_trades/positions_tradesPositions"]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/span/text()')
results_long = tree.xpath('//*[@id="flexBox_flex_trades/positions_tradesPositions"]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/span/text()')
```

Then apply the strip function as mentioned above, you should be able to get the correct results.